Using QGIS to generate drill sections
I am trying to create drill sections with QGIS. But I can't get the elements below to show:

Depths of the DDH
"From" "To" points on the section plan

The section I generated currently looks like the picture attached.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
I tried opening the attribute table of the Z grid, but wasn't sure what I should change the numbers to or if I should change them at all.
